# edit in datarow bound

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit, datarow

i have gridview with many col some of col will sum and display in total col using rowdatabound and it works only in view, but the problem when i try to edit using edit statement that gridview have this error appear (Troubleshooting exceptions: system.nullreferenceexception)

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string val1 = e.Row.Cells[13].Text; //Gets the value in Column 1
        string val2 = e.Row.Cells[14].Text; //Gets the value in Column 2
        string val3 = e.Row.Cells[15].Text; //Gets the value in Column 3
        string val4 = e.Row.Cells[16].Text; //Gets the value in Column 4
        Label lblTotal = (Label)e.Row.Cells[12].FindControl("Label1"); //
        float _val1, _val2, _val3, _val4;

        float.TryParse(val1, out _val1);
        float.TryParse(val2, out _val2);
        float.TryParse(val3, out _val3);
        float.TryParse(val4, out _val4);

        float sum = _val1 + _val2 + _val3 + _val4;
        lblTotal.Text += sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `DataRow` is in edit mode.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {
        //row is in edit mode
    }
    else
    {
        //a normal row
    }
}
```

Comment: sir plz help didnt work still get the same error can u give me ur email

Comment: THX Sir its work if u wana some job with (online-job) u can give me ur email